# Is union type suitable for similar/hierarchical angular 2 model classes?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, casting, angular2-template

If I had 3 similar angular models having common and unique fields, should I go with union type `M1|M2|M3`or define one complete type `M3` with missing fields set to null?

```
class M1 {
  field1: string;
} 
class M2 extends M1 {
  field2: string;
} 
class M3 extends M2 {
  field3: string;
}
```

I could define union type for all similar tasks and then check with `instanceof` if I need specific one.

```
getModel(): M1|M2|M3 {
}
...
model: M1|M2|M3
...
this.model = getModel();
if(this.model instanceof M3){
...
}
```

But then I would need an overhead of casting type to a template, we can't reference `<span>{{model.field3}}</span>` in a Union variable, we do need to cast it every time by some method.

```
asM3(model) { return model as M3; }
```

Wouldn't this result in performance drop, if we had to cast every time accessing a M3 property? * *if you do know a better way, please tell me :)*

In Angular 1.x and JS, I'd go with `<span ng-if="model.field3">{{model.field3}}</span>`

Finally, is union type suitable for similar/hierarchical angular 2 model classes? Or should I just go with the widest type of M3 and then check not for types, but for present fields, as in pure JS?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the performance that worries me about this style of programming - it is maintainability. You end up with too much code tied to the specific types.

If you replace `M2` with another suitable type that has a compatible structure, it will fail the `instanceof` check even though it has the property. Then you end up chasing your type checks throughout the program.

If possible, make the check simpler, for example:

```
interface M {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
    field3: string;
}
```

Then, using the weak type `M` you can test whether the property has a value (this will ensure `field2` is not `null`, `undefined`, or an empty `''`:

```
this.model = getModel();
if (this.model.field2) {
    // ...
}
```

This means you are not bound to the implementation types, if you have an `M3B` class later that replaces `M3`, your code will still work.

## Automatic Weak Type

If you don't want to change the weak interface each time you add a property to one of your three classes, you can create a type using the following:

```
interface M extends M1, M2, M3 {
}

type PartialM = Partial<M>;
```

The `PartialM` type has the properties of all three classes, and they are all optional due the ready-to-use `Partial` mapped type.

Comment: Angular style guide suggests using classes instead of interfaces for models.
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

How could I check if model is M3, without checking every field and `instanceof` working only with classes ?

Types could be reused when defined in a type alias, like

`type ModelUnion = M1 | M2 | M3;`

Comment: But otherwise yeah, I was asking the same thing, I could create the same class and even define methods like isM3() checking for all 3 fields present.  

class M {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
    field3: string;
}

The same "super" class can be created using implements or extends keywords, when we do add fields in child classes we'll receive them in the super class.